# Regular Expressions in refs (i.e., \ref{tab:foo.*} )

Tags: cross-referencing

Sometimes I want to refer to a long list of tables or figures. I've labelled them in categorical ways, but it's a lot of typing (I'm lazy programmer) to type out something like:

```
\ref{tab:foo1}, \ref{tab:foo2}, \ref{tab:foo3}, \ref{tab:foo4}
```

the ideal result of which looks like :

> 1, 2, 3, 4

Wouldn't it be nice if I could just use regexes here instead? That is:

```
\ref{tab:foo.*}
```

Or, even better :

```
\ref{tab:foo[0-9]*}
```

I'm not very hopeful that this exists. I'm mostly just curious : Does anyone know of a package that enables this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `l3regex` module of LaTeX3 can be beneficial.

You use `\lazylabel` for labeling the objects and `\lazyref` with a regex as its argument.

Actually there is support for "classes" of labels, which is left as an exercise.

Consult the documentation of `l3regex` for checking the precise syntax of regular expressions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_clear_new:N \g_lazylabel_alllabels_seq
\seq_new:N \l_lazylabel_temp_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\lazylabel}{O{alllabels}m}
 {
  \label{#2}
  \seq_if_in:cnF { g_lazylabel_#1_seq } { #2 }
   { \seq_gput_right:cn { g_lazylabel_#1_seq } { #2 } }
  \iow_shipout:cn { @auxout } { \newlazylabel { #1 } { #2 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \iow_shipout:Nn { c }

\NewDocumentCommand{\newlazylabel}{m m}
 {
  \seq_if_exist:cF { g_lazylabel_#1_seq }
   { \seq_new:c { g_lazylabel_#1_seq } }
  \seq_if_in:cnF { g_lazylabel_#1_seq } { #2 }
   { \seq_gput_right:cn { g_lazylabel_#1_seq } { #2 } }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\definelabelclass}{m}
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { g_lazylabel_#1_seq }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\lazyref}{O{alllabels} m}
 {
  \lazylabel_extract:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \lazylabel_extract:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_lazylabel_temp_seq
  \seq_map_inline:cn { g_lazylabel_#1_seq }
   {
    \regex_match:nnT { #2 } { ##1 } 
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l_lazylabel_temp_seq { \ref{##1} }
     }
   }
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l_lazylabel_temp_seq { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ~and~ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

In sections \lazyref{sec:*} \dots


\section{a}\lazylabel{sec:a}
\section{b}\lazylabel{sec:b}
\begin{table}
\caption{a}\lazylabel{tab:foo}
\caption{a}\lazylabel{tab:foo1}
\caption{a}\lazylabel{tab:foo2}
\caption{a}\lazylabel{tab:bar1}
\end{table}


See tables \lazyref{tab:foo[1-9]+}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that should go to CTAN verbatim.

Comment: Remarkably (to me at least!), the `\lazylabel`s and `\lazyref`s even play nicely with `hyperref`.

Comment: @Mico I use only the standard `\label` and `\ref` for establishing the cross references. :)

Comment: What's so neat is that the translation from `\lazy[label,ref]` to the ordinary commands is taken care of so well.

Comment: This is awesome. I'm actually a little startled that there was an answer. I'm glad to find I'm not the only person who has ever wanted this feature!

Answer (score 10):

TeX and LaTeX aren't set up very well to "do" regular expressions, at least not without a lot of extra programming. However, you may be in luck nevertheless: the `cleveref` package may do what you're looking to do.

For instance, the command

```
\crefrange{tab:foo1}{tab:foo4}
```

will typeset `Tables 1 to 4`; this assumes, of course, that the table labeled `{tab:foo1}` is numbered `1` and that the table labeled `{tab:foo4}` is numbered `4`. If instead they're numbered 22 and 25, the command `\crefrange{tab:foo1}{tab:foo4}` will generate `Tables 22 to 25`.

The `\crefrange` command is appropriate if the first and last labels point to items (here: tables, right?) that are numbered consecutively. If that's not the case, you could use the command

```
\cref{tab:foo1,tab:foo2,tab:foo3,tab:foo4}
```

and let the `cleveref` package do the job of sorting and (if necessary) compressing the references. For instance, if the four tables are numbered `3`, `4`, `5`, and `8`, the `\cref` command above will generate `Tables 3 to 5 and 8`. If you do not want compression of consecutive numbers, be sure to load the package with the option `[sort]`; this will result in the following typeset output: `Tables 3, 4, 5 and 8`.

If, for some reason, you do *not* want to include the cross-referenced items' "name" (here: `Table`) in the cross-reference -- presumably because you would want to supply it yourself -- you could use the command `\labelcref` instead of `\cref`.

Finally, if you use the `hyperref` package as well, be sure to load `cleveref` *after* `hyperref`.

Comment: It was really hard to decide which one of these was what I wanted. Sorry to pick the other answer. Yours is great! Thanks!